# How to insert slide in README.md

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown, readme

I want to insert images in a slider in my README.md

I have inserted a single image like this

```
![image-name](image-url)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[There is no way to display a slideshow in Github Flavored Markdown.](https://github.github.com/gfm/)

If you want to display multiple images without making your README excessively long, you can use a `<details>` tag:

```markdown
<details>
  <summary>The title of the image group</summary>
  <img src="image-url" alt="image-description"/>
  <img src="image-url" alt="image-description"/>
  <img src="image-url" alt="image-description"/>
</details>
```

The images will be grouped in a widget that can be clicked to show or hide the content inside:

[image: open]

[image: closed]

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. But It's not the one i am looking for. And YES we can add a slideshow in README files.

Comment: Can you send a link to an example?

Comment: I want to make like this (http://vishalgupta.me/md-slides/)

Comment: That's not a GitHub README, that's a presentation [made with reveal.js](https://revealjs.com/)...

Comment: OK. Thanks for the answer